# Remove [] in Python

Tags: python

I have a list like this:

```
data = [[[1, 2], [1, 1], [2, 3], [5, 5], [6, 6]]]
```

I would like to get like this :

```
data = [[1, 2], [1, 1], [2, 3], [5, 5], [6, 6]]
```

How can i do using python ?

Comment: `data=data[0]`?

Comment: also you can erase a pair of brackets using the erase button on your keyboard

Answer (score 3):

Reassign data with the 0 index of your array.

data = data [0]